# Free Hand Drawing in Mac OS using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, whiteboard

Is it possible to draw a free hand path using Objective C on Mac OS application views?

I'm trying to draw with NSBBezierPath and able to draw basic shapes like line,circle,etc..,

But, is it possible to draw a free hand path using NSBezierPath?

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a subclass of NSView to use as your drawing board, you can implement the mouseDragged: method (or any of the other mouse methods) and use it to capture mouse movements.

```
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint mouseLoc = [self.superview convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

    // Do something with mouseLoc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you detect the location of the `free hand input` you want and get the associated screen points then you can create a bezier path and use `moveToPoint:` (with the first point) and `lineToPoint:` (with the latter points) to add the points and specify the path.